# Removing small segments of geometry from shapefile using FME?

Tags: road, fme-form

I am working on road dataset on a country level.

The gdb contains the entire road network which we have extracted from 3rd party source provider.

But the road network which we have fetched contains a lot of small dangling edges.

[image]

How can I remove all of such dangling nodes in bulk using FME?

I cannot do it manually, but it will take a lot of time and the sheer number of such dangling nodes are in lakhs.

Also I am not able to find the transformers like MRF2DCleaner and MRF2DDangleRemover as I am limited by the licencing level.

Comment: In FME, the TopologyBuilder could help you identify dangles. You can then easily select the nodes where only one edge is connected, and select that edge, using the node_id and edge_id values. However, it could also select valid edges. How long are those dangles? Are they really small? Do you have any systematic way to distinguish a real street (ex. dead-end street) from a dangling edge, like perhaps an attribute containing street names or addresses, etc, or just the length?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the tutorial on data QA on the FME knowledge base: https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/32707/tutorial-data-validation-and-qa-with-fme.html

In general you can create topology with the Topology builder, and from that ascertain which lines are only connected at one end. If you need to filter further, then a LengthCalculator will tell you if it’s a long or short line.

You may want/need to run the Intersector transformer too first. It will help clean the network, if necessary, and has the nice new tolerance setting to help reduce little sections, tiny overshoots, etc